# How to write CSS in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I wanted to make a Memory Game. I want to write an CSS animation for the flip in JS so I can then call a function, because I wanted to make a onclick anmation an not an hover animation.

how do I make a CSS flip animation with an oncklicked Function in Javascript?

```js
var card = "<div class='flip-card'><div class='flip-card-inner'><div class='flip-card-front'><button id='button'onclick='Flipfront()'style='width:300px;height:300px; marign:50px; background-image:url(Frontpage.jpg);'></button></div><div class='flip-card-back'><button id='button2' onclick='Flipback()'style='width:300px;height:300px; marign:50px; background-image:url(IMG1.jpg);'></button></div></div></div>"

for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  document.querySelector("#container").innerHTML += card;
}

function Flipfront() { 
  // ?
}

function Flipback() { 
  // ?
}
```

```css
.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  perspective: 1000px;
  /* Remove this if you don't want the 3D effect */
}


/* This container is needed to position the front and back side */

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}


/* Do an horizontal flip when you move the mouse over the flip box container */

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}


/* Position the front and back side */

.flip-card-front,
.flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* Safari */
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}


/* Style the front side (fallback if image is missing) */

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}


/* Style the back side */

.flip-card-back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="outerbackground">
  <img src="background.jpg" class="backgorund" border="1" id="BG">
</div>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Use JS to toggle a class that turns the card around.

Comment: @Terry that is my Idea, but what do I wirte in the class ?

Answer (score 1):

To further elabourate on my comment: instead of using `:hover`, you can use a class, say `.flipped` instead, to control the flipped state of the card.

Then, in the `Flipfront()` and `Flipback()` methods, make sure you accept an argument that will be passed in from your markup, which will be invoked as `Flipfront(this)` or `Flipback(this)`. This will allow you to access the element that triggered it.

Then, simply use [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) to access the `.flip-card` parent, and use `Element.classList.add()` or `Element.classList.remove()` to toggle the `flipped` class:

```js
var card = "<div class='flip-card'><div class='flip-card-inner'><div class='flip-card-front'><button id='button'onclick='Flipfront(this)'style='width:300px;height:300px; marign:50px; background-image:url(Frontpage.jpg);'></button></div><div class='flip-card-back'><button id='button2' onclick='Flipback(this)'style='width:300px;height:300px; marign:50px; background-image:url(IMG1.jpg);'></button></div></div></div>"

for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  document.querySelector("#container").innerHTML += card;
}

function Flipfront(el) { 
  el.closest('.flip-card').classList.add('flipped');
}

function Flipback(el) { 
  el.closest('.flip-card').classList.remove('flipped');
}
```

```css
.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  perspective: 1000px;
  /* Remove this if you don't want the 3D effect */
}


/* This container is needed to position the front and back side */

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}


/* Do an horizontal flip when you move the mouse over the flip box container */

.flip-card.flipped .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}


/* Position the front and back side */

.flip-card-front,
.flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* Safari */
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}


/* Style the front side (fallback if image is missing) */

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}


/* Style the back side */

.flip-card-back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="outerbackground">
  <img src="background.jpg" class="backgorund" border="1" id="BG">
</div>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried dynamically changing classes on click? 
When the element is clicked, you can add the class `.flip-card-inner` and remove '.flip-card-front` by using the [classlist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) property and its methods

Usage is:

`elem.classList.add("flip-card-inner");`

`elem.classList.remove("flip-card-front");`

Answer (score 1):

Don't write CSS in JS. Instead simply change the `:hover` rule to depend on a class which you toggle when each `.flip-card` is clicked.

Also note that you should not be using `onX` attributes as they are outdated and bad practice due to violating the separation of concerns principle. Instead use unobtrusive event handlers. The same is also true for inline `style` attributes. Move those rules in to an external stylesheet. Here's a working example:

```js
let card = '<div class="flip-card"><div class="flip-card-inner"><div class="flip-card-front"><button id="button"></button></div><div class="flip-card-back"><button id="button2"></button></div></div></div>';
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  document.querySelector("#container").innerHTML += card;
}

document.querySelectorAll('.flip-card').forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', () => el.classList.toggle('flipped'));
});
```

```css
.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

/* remove :hover here */
.flip-card.flipped .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front,
.flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* Safari */
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}

.flip-card-back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

#button {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url(Frontpage.jpg);
}

#button2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url(IMG1.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div id="outerbackground">
  <img src="background.jpg" class="backgorund" border="1" id="BG">
</div>
<div id="container"></div>
```